# Creating objects with complex variables from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a checkbox, each checkbox has a value of something like this: "case-color-id"

e.g.

1. case1-red-1
2. case2-blue-2
3. case1-blue-4
4. case3-green-3

What i'm trying to do is to create a json with those values. The end result would be something like:

```
cases:[
    {
      case1:[
             {
               id : '1'
               color: 'red'
             },
             {
               id: '4'
               color: 'blue'
             }
            ],
      case2:[
             {
               id : '2'
               color: 'blue'
             }
            ],
      case3:[
             {
               id : '3'
               color: 'green'
             }
            ]       
       }
      ]
```

I need help on the logic in inserting the objects with jquery/javascript

```
$('#checkbox :checkbox:checked').each(function (index, element) {

        var case = $('this').val().split('-')[0];
        var color = $('this').val().split('-')[1];
        var id = $('this').val().split('-')[2];

   var caseHolderObject = new Object();

   // create objects here and insert the values depending which case it belongs to

   // Then get the jsonString
   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(caseHolderObject));

}
```

Comment: FYI there's no such thing as a 'JSON object', they're just plain old objects

Comment: sorry, updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var cases = [{}];
$('#checkbox :checkbox:checked').each(function (index, element) {
    var cas = $(this).val().split('-')[0];
    var color = $(this).val().split('-')[1];
    var id = $(this).val().split('-')[2];
    var obj = {
        id: id,
        color: color
    };
    var ary = [obj];
    if (cases[0][cas]) {
        cases[0][cas].push(obj);
    } else {
        cases[0][cas] = ary;
    }
});
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cases);
```

[**See working DEMO.**](https://jsfiddle.net/hiral/bLh1Lans/)

Answer (score 0):

check this script i tried most of your requirement in it , if you need updates let me know :

```
    function retriever(){
var caseObject = new Object();
$(':checkbox:checked').each(function () {

   var caseHolderObject = new Object();
   var caseVal = $(this).val().split('-')[0];
    var color = $(this).val().split('-')[1];
    var id = $(this).val().split('-')[2];
caseHolderObject['color']=color;
caseHolderObject['id']=id;
    caseObject[caseVal]=caseHolderObject;
});

   var jsonString = JSON.stringify(caseObject);
    alert(jsonString);
}


HTML :
<input type="checkbox" value="case1-red-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="case1" value="case2-red-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="case2" value="case4-red-4">
<input type="checkbox" name="case3" value="case3-red-3">
<button onclick="retriever()">here</button>
```

Comment: please feel free to add your code to the answer and add a clickable link.
If your fiddle will stop working, your answer gets useless